# SQL Query Optimization with 'WHERE' 'AND' clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, where-clause

I am trying to optimize a long query and also improve its readability. 
Do WHERE clause with AND keyword doesn't read the indexes properly or affects the performance of reads?

Example:
The table tblTransactions contains 61,795 records

```
DECLARE @DateTypeId INT = 1 
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '01/01/2000' 
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '01/01/2019'

SELECT *
FROM tblTransactions ts
WHERE (((ts.TransactionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) AND @DateTypeId = 1)
        OR ((ts.PostingDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate) AND @DateTypeId = 2))
```

The total time of execution is **9 seconds**. This is the other example of the query.

```
DECLARE @DateTypeId INT = 1
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '01/01/2000'
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '01/01/2019'

IF @DateTypeId = 1
    SELECT *
    FROM tblTransactions ts
    WHERE ts.TransactionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

ELSE IF @DateTypeId = 2
    SELECT *
    FROM tblTransactions ts
    WHERE ts.PostingDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

The execution time for this query is **8 - 9 seconds**. In terms of readability I prefer the first query but in terms of performance I prefer the second one. But if the query is too long which is the suggested query to be executed?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific. And performance questions too.)

Comment: could you post the query plan as well? do you have an index on `TransactionDate` and `PostingDate`?

Comment: Please add the tag for the database product you are using (looks like T-SQL/SQL Server)

Comment: Could you, just as an experiment, add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of your queries, run them like that and let us know the results?

Comment: Both should be identical. SQL Server is able to short-circuit WHERE clauses based on variable values. Could you run both queries after running the below two statements and paste the messages generated? SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

Comment: @RnP - the issue is that SQL Server needs to compile a plan that will work correctly for whatever parameter value. Not one optimised to seek on the specific index. These "catch all" queries are problematic unless `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` can be used

Comment: SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2340 ms,  elapsed time = 9214 ms. This is for the Query with AND and OR clause.   CPU time = 2636 ms,  elapsed time = 15603 ms.This is for the query with IF ELSE statement

Comment: What does the OPTION (RECOMPILE) does exactly? Based on what I've searched it is an optimizer.... so it is for the good to have this line of code to any queries created?

Comment: ZeroCool your CPU times indicate the times are roughly the same. In fact, it seems the total time spent is now reversed. 
@Martin Smith, SQL is able to generate a single plan with multiple branches that use the appropriate index and short circuit entire branches upon execution using what's called in a query plan as a 'Startup Expression Predicate' . See this sample query plan for an example: https://pasteboard.co/HfX8zJy.png

Comment: See https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/04/hold-fiiter-startup-expression-predicates/ for a more thourough explanation of situations like this when it comes to performance

Comment: @RnP - yep I know about startup expressions. I didn't test this specific case!

Answer (score 0):

Optimization is a delicate task.. It greatly depends on a moltitude of subjects..

It is important to know the table structure (columns, data, indexes), 
It is important to know the query you want to do (the columns in your select and joins and/or functions involved)

We should talk also about of your hardware and your sql-server version, but it will become a very deep analysis..

Let's try to simplify a bit.

If your indexes are not useful to retrieve selected columns (I'm not talking about filtering the rows) optimizer will (almost) not use them and it will go straight for a full table scan on clustered index (you MUST have at least this).

If your select is as simple as in your question (`select * from tblTransactions`) we must think about table structure..

So, the point is, if you select only a few columns, you can build an index with these columns included and it will be used and you will be very happy (sure?).

When you include columns in an index they are not part of the index key, but are used just as payload data..

The problem is that included columns, take as much space in the index as they have in the table.. so if you have thousands of records with big columns you will produce huge indexes for the data duplication involved.

After all that considerations, you could build up your super index, with all selected columns included.. and maybe you can find out that total query execution time is almost the same..

Much of the time spent is not to find which data to extract but the I/O operations to retrieve and put them in your output.

Ok, now some advices and options:

1) I will keep the `IF/ELSE` version, the simpler the better..

2) try to add indexes with the included columns you have in your `SELECT` (use your names..) and run your query, check if they was used and if you have a performance improvement

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TRAN_DATE-INCL-COLS]
ON [dbo].[tblTransactions] ([TransactionDate])
INCLUDE ([PostingDate],[Col1],[Col2],[Col3])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_POST_DATE-INCL-COLS]
ON [dbo].[tblTransactions] ([PostingDate])
INCLUDE ([TransactionDate],[Col1],[Col2],[Col3])
```

3) you can try a mixed solution, simpler indexes and a tricky query

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TRAN_DATE]
ON [dbo].[tblTransactions] ([TransactionDate])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_POST_DATE]
ON [dbo].[tblTransactions] ([PostingDate])

DECLARE @IDX TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY)

IF @DateTypeId = 1 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @IDX
    SELECT ts.TransactionID
    FROM tblTransactions ts
    WHERE ts.TransactionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

END ELSE IF @DateTypeId = 2 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @IDX
    SELECT ts.TransactionID
    FROM tblTransactions ts
    WHERE ts.PostingDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

END
```

Each of the above is to test.. and (maybe) it could be useless..

I hope it would be useful to understand a little, the great problem of optimization.

Answer (score -1):

Please try for better performance:

```
 DECLARE @DateTypeId INT = 1
 DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '01/01/2000'
 DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '01/01/2019'

 IF @DateTypeId = 1
 SELECT *
 FROM tblTransactions ts
 WHERE  @FromDate >= ts.TransactionDate <= @ToDate

 ELSE IF @DateTypeId = 2
 SELECT *
 FROM tblTransactions ts
 WHERE  @FromDate >= ts.PostingDate <= @ToDate
```

Comment: The only thing you changed is `BETWEEN` -> `>=` AND `<=`. However, in the background SQL Server does that by itself so you **have not** improved SARGability of the query by turning it to `>=` AND `<=`. **EDIT**: on second sight, I see your query isn't even valid.

Comment: That's invalid syntax - at least for SQL server. So can't reason with the better performance claim.

Answer (score -1):

As the separate queries run about as long as the combined one, I'd stay with the combined one (i.e. the first query that you, too, prefer).

The only criteria in your query is the dates, in one case `TransactionDate`, in the other `PostingDate`. Make sure you have separate indexes on them, so as to give the DBMS the option to look up the date ranges there:

```
create index idx_transact_transaction_date on tbltransactions(transactiondate);
create index idx_transact_posting_date on tbltransactions(postingdate);
```